# TensorFlowInferenceInterface returning low values

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras

I am writing an Android app that uses a Keras model through a .pb file to classify a leaf as healthy or unhealthy. I am interfacing this using TensorFlow with Android, specifically the TensorFlowInferenceInterface class. My code referencing this is below:

> inferenceInterface.feed("conv2d_1_input", input, 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3);
>           inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"activation_7/Sigmoid"});
>           inferenceInterface.fetch("activation_7/Sigmoid", output);

When I run the .pb network from a Jupyter Notebook using Keras, it outputs values in the usual range (0 to 1). However, when I run it using the above code and the exact same image file, it never gives a value above 0.1, which indicates very unhealthy leaves. Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question when you run on jupyter notebook after training you get the correct output but when running using Tensorflow inference interface you are getting wrong results.

See to run a .pb in Android using Tensorflow Mobile you first need to freeze all the variables (convert all the trainable and non trainable Variables in the graph to constants).

See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) module of Tensorflow to freeze a protocol buffer (.pb)

After you got them freezed, you need to optimize the graph, usually graph will have most of the ops which you will not need during inference, so you need to remove them by optimizing the graph.

See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference_lib.py) module of Tensorflow to optimize the protocol buffer

Finally run this .pb in android.

Let me know if you did all those steps!

Comment: I've done all of that, but I still get the aforementioned error.

Comment: Okay please post your pbtxt.